# Did the final act of the Inquisitor screw up everything they'd tried to prevent?

Tags: dragon-age

The Inquisitor spends the entirety of the game doing two things: stabilizing the fade by closing rifts and...

> making sure that Corypheus can't stride bodily into the Fade so he can't realize his desire to become a god.

This is all well and good for the majority of the game, with the Inquisitor and his/her allies kicking butt and taking names, building their power to accomplish the necessary tasks in service to this greater goal. Then, having done their best to thwart the tide of darkness and...

> made sure that Corypheus can't get back into the fade via the Anchor or the Eluvian, the Inquisitor finishes the final fight and as a final act, uses their anchor and the power of the orb to...send him bodily into the Fade.

Did the Inquisitor, in a final act of spite, make their actions of the rest of the game moot?!?!

Comment: Is there a reason why this question was downvoted? Is this not an issue with plot-inconsistency regarding Dragon Age Inquisition? Did I apply the spoiler tags incorrectly? Why the downvote?

Comment: I honestly can't think of a reason this would be downvoted except for the fandom being angry about stuff. But that's fairly normal for the Dragon Age fandom as far as I've seen.

Answer (score 4):

While yes he was sent into the fade, he was sent in a severely weakened state due to his fight with the inquisitor. It could be possible he survived, though when teams of mages were sent to scour the Fade in search of any remains of Corypheus, nothing could be found. This is briefly mentioned the World of Thedas Volume 2.

Also, remember his plan, it wasn't just to enter the fade, but to use the anchor and the orb to gain access to the Black City, granting him God status. Without the Orb and Anchor, he no longer has that capability. So as to his ultimate fate, we don't know, but his being in the fade would be an extreme hindrance, especially in his condition. In my opinion, it is unlikely he would survive long in the Fade.

So no is the answer to your question.

Also I'm not sure why it was downvoted, this site doesn't have enough DA!

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of would relate to Hatandboots answer, that he was severely weakened after his fight. However, there is also the possibility that he knows some spirits would not necessarily be terribly happy about the Breach and how it pulled them through anyways. That or he might not survive the transportation into the Fade. My best guess, but I'm probably way off.